# How do I incorporate product managers with Backlog control into JIRA?

Tags: agile, process, jira, project-management-style, backlog

My company has several product offerings, each with a dedicated development team, plus a number of people on the business side that control the product's direction.

We currently use a homegrown ticketing solution that allows business to create tickets, work with project managers to gather requirements, and eventually drop the tickets on a product's development queue. The business owner of that product controls the order of the backlog.

In JIRA, what is the optimal way to get this functionality across?

I understand JIRA Software now has the concept of "business projects" and "software projects". Should I move tickets from one to the other? Business doesn't need to see all of the development fluff we need for day-to-day operations, and we do not need to see what they are currently planning on their side.

Comment: Do you also use Confluence? I occasionally see people (ab)using Confluence to manage business information and JIRA for action items. The two can be linked.

Comment: We do plan on using Confluence. I've gone down that road before, and I will make sure they know the two can be linked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a lot of teams will do is to use the [user story](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories) format for requirements and sub-tasks for implementation details.

The stories are written in the language of your business users, so they can easily understand what the value of each story is. JIRA hides the sub-tasks in the [backlog view](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/using-a-board/using-the-backlog) of a board, so business users aren't exposed to the technical details of implementation.

There are several advantages to this approach:

- Business users can see where there requests are in the backlog
- Business users get to see what their requirements are *competing against*
- The development team can see what is coming along in the future - allowing them to prepare for it early
- Anyone who wants to see what the team has on its backlog can see it in one location in JIRA

Comment: That is an excellent idea. I like the idea of keeping our concerns separate. Thank you!